# User based custom subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've tried to research and figure out how people are doing this without much success.

For my rails project I have projects that each have their own slug. The user can themselves dictate the slug and that slug will be the subdomain.

Now I'm trying to figure out how to do this routing wise and make it work in production as-well.

I have this now:

```
get '/', to: 'posts#index', constraints: { subdomain: /.+/, via: [:get] }, as: :feed
```

At a controller level I do:

```
before_action :get_project, only: :index
...
def get_project
  unless @project ||= Project.find_by_slug(request.subdomain)
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

When I test this on localhost using lvh.me it works. However when I try to do this on a live production server and check server logs, Rails return this:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [OPTIONS] "/"):
```

Does anybody have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

As for why your current code doesn't work in production you'd need to give us your web server's configuration if we are to help you debug it since that is probably the main difference between the two environments. Especially if your app is served behind a reverse proxy. But you may be able to solve this using this [gem](https://github.com/mholling/subdomain_routes). Their implementation of this covers several cases and simplifies what your trying to achieve and may end up working in production. It allows mapping of subdomain routes in several ways that really saves a lot of time. What you might be really interested in is [this section](https://github.com/mholling/subdomain_routes#defining-model-based-subdomain-routes) that talks about mapping routes with active record.